# How to tell if boto.sqs.Queue.write() succeeded?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

All documentation of this method that I can find says that Queue.write returns True or False, depending on whether the write succeeded, but this doesn't square with reality.

The docs say:

> The write method returns a True if everything went well. If the write
>   didn't succeed it will either return a False (meaning SQS simply chose
>   not to write the message for some reason) or an exception if there was
>   some sort of problem with the request.

But in fact the method simply returns the message that gets passed in. Here is the relevant source code from https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/sqs/queue.py:

```
def write(self, message, delay_seconds=None):
    """
    Add a single message to the queue.
    :type message: Message
    :param message: The message to be written to the queue

    :rtype: :class:`boto.sqs.message.Message`
    :return: The :class:`boto.sqs.message.Message` object that was written.
    """
    new_msg = self.connection.send_message(self,
                                           message.get_body_encoded(),
                                           delay_seconds)
    message.id = new_msg.id
    message.md5 = new_msg.md5
    return message
```

My question then is: How do I really tell if the write was successful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation quote you provide comes from the SQS tutorial.  The [SQS API docs](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/sqs.html#boto.sqs.queue.Queue.write_batch) correctly describe the current return value.  The SQS tutorial is simply out of date and needs to be corrected.  I have created an [issue](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/1985) to track this.

If the write fails for any reason, the service will return an HTTP error code which, in turn, will cause boto to raise an SQSError exception.  If no exception is raised, the write was successful.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. Is it true in general that Boto methods raise exceptions rather than returning an error? I didn't see a mention of an exception being raised in the docs you linked.

Comment: Yes, that is generally the case.  Since most of the API calls are similar across services, the actual code to make the calls is shared across modules.  And all of the Amazon Web Services use HTTP error codes to communicate status.  So boto checks those HTTP response codes and raises Python exceptions when errors are detected.  We should do a better job of documenting the exceptions that can be raised.